# Repeat the function every time

Tags: html, jquery-plugins

```
 function fader(){
    $('#numbers').animate({backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}, 900);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="numbers" style="background-color: blue; width:200px;" onclick="fader()">1234567890</div>
```

The code above changes the background color of the div from blue to white on click event. But it works for the first click only.

How to change the color every time I click on the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You need to make it blue again!

```
function fader()
{
    $('#numbers')
        .css('background-color', '#FF0000')
        .animate({
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        }, 900);
}
```

Comment: ~ Thanks For Helping This Newbie. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `background-color` using a separate CSS style rather than using inline CSS.